# How to assign the Variable which is the result of query PL/SQL ORACLE

Tags: oracle, variables, plsql

[image]

Good Morning, I am very new to PL/SQL, I do not know why this is causing error.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

DECLARE      

  designation VARCHAR2(3000);

BEGIN           
       SELECT LISTAGG(x.ACCOUNT, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY NULL) AS ACCOUNT
     INTO designation           
     FROM acctx x
     where x.OBJECT_ID = 1;



     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(designation); 
END;
/
```

The error is

> ORA-0092; missing or invalid option

the resulf of this query

```
SELECT LISTAGG(x.ACCOUNT, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY NULL) AS ACCOUNT

     FROM acctx x
     where x.OBJECT_ID = 1;
```

is

```
6012,6061,6082,6068,6018
```

Comment: Are you sure the error is coming from that code, not something else in your script? Which client are you running this in? It seems to work fine in 11g via SQL Developer.

Comment: after SET SERVEROUTPUT ON there isn't ;

Can you tell us the line of error?

Comment: Works for me (using a different table). `as account` is redundant, but it works with or without (tested on 11.2.0.2).

Comment: ORA_06550:line 3, column11:

Comment: I posted the error picture. I also use oracle 11g.

Comment: OK, again, which client? And how are you running it? It seems to be starting the execution from BEGIN, looking at the line numbers, so it isn't doing the DECLARE part. That looks like a client problem. Maybe try it without the blank line before BEGIN and see what happens... (And that isn't the error you initially said you got!)

Comment: What front-end client are you using?  11g is the database version.

Comment: I got it, I deleted it, "SET SERVEROUTPUT ON", it started to work. Thank you so much everybody!!!

Comment: Strange, PL/SQL Developer gives me `ORA-00922: missing or invalid option`. (`SET SERVEROUTPUT ON` is a SQL*Plus command. In PL/SQL Developer and similar tools, you use the checkbox provided.)

Comment: Right, so you got both errors; everything from `set serveroutput on` to the semicolon after the declaration of `designation` was seen as a single, invalid command; and then the remaining code was seen as a block with no declare section.